# Função retornando undefined javascript

Tags: javascript

tenho tentando retornar uma função onde testa se o programador tem a habilidade css; As habilidades são salvas dentro de um array, porém no retorno sempre o resultado é undefined. podem me ajudar?

```
const usuarios = [
    {
        nome: 'Carlos',
        tecnologia:['Javascript','css' ]

    },
    {
        nome: 'leo',
        tecnologia:['js','css']
    }


]



for(let i=0;i<usuarios.length;i++)
{
{
    console.log(`Usuario com sua tecnologia ${usuarios[i].nome} ${usuarios[i].tecnologia}`)
}
}
function testacss(usuarios)
{
for(let i=0; i< usuarios.length; i++)
  {

      if(usuarios.tecnologia[i] == 'css')
      {

        return true
      }
      else {

        return false
      }


  }
}


for(let i =0; i< usuarios.length; i++)
{
    const usuariostrabalhacomcss = testacss(usuarios[i])
    if(usuariostrabalhacomcss){

        console.log(`O usuario ${usuarios[i].nome} trabalha com css`)
    }else{
        console.log(usuariostrabalhacomcss)

    }
}
```

Comment: Apenas mude a função `testacss()` para  `function testacss(usuarios) {  return usuarios.tecnologia.includes('css');}`

Answer (score 1):

A função `testacss` recebe como parâmetro um usuário e você precisa procurar o valor `'css'` na propriedade `tecnologia` desse usuário recebido, porém você faz o loop direto no usuário:

```
for(let i=0; i< usuarios.length; i++)
```

Corrija essa parte, trabalhando com a propriedade `tecnologia` do usuário recebido no parâmetro:

```
for(let i=0; i< usuarios.tecnologia.length; i++)
```

---

Após essa correção, perceba que sempre será retornado falso, pois sua função retorna `false` caso a primeira verificação não seja igual a `'css'`:

```
if(usuarios.tecnologia[i] == 'css')
{

    return true
}
else {

    return false
}
```

O que pode ser feito aqui, é retorna true caso seja igual a `'css'` e retorna false após o término do loop:

```
for(let i=0; i< usuarios.tecnologia.length; i++) { 
    if(usuarios.tecnologia[i] == 'css') {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

---

Com isso, seu código final ficará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```js
const usuarios = [
    {
        nome: 'Carlos',
        tecnologia:['Javascript','css' ]

    },
    {
        nome: 'leo',
        tecnologia:['js','css']
    }
];

for(let i=0;i<usuarios.length;i++) {
    console.log(`Usuario com sua tecnologia ${usuarios[i].nome} ${usuarios[i].tecnologia}`);
}

function testacss(usuarios) {
    for(let i=0; i< usuarios.tecnologia.length; i++) { 
        if(usuarios.tecnologia[i] == 'css') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

for(let i =0; i< usuarios.length; i++) {
    const usuariostrabalhacomcss = testacss(usuarios[i]);

    if(usuariostrabalhacomcss){
        console.log(`O usuario ${usuarios[i].nome} trabalha com css`)
    }else{
        console.log(usuariostrabalhacomcss)
    }
}
```

---

Por fim, caso você queira procurar um valor em um array em JS, é muito prático utilizar por exemplo o método `includes`, veja um exemplo:

```js
const usuarios = [
    {
        nome: 'Carlos',
        tecnologia:['Javascript','css' ]

    },
    {
        nome: 'leo',
        tecnologia:['js','css']
    }
];

console.log( usuarios[0].tecnologia.includes('css') );

console.log( usuarios[1].tecnologia.includes('css') );
```

> Documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains

Comment: Daniel fantástico. Deu super certo. Obrigado irmão